# Consequences of variable sample rate in waveguide synthesis?

Tags: signal-synthesis

I'm making musical 'woodwind' type oscillators using digital delays with feedback, similar to these: [A Meta-Wind-Instrument Physical Model, and a Meta-Controller for Real-Time Performance Control](http://hdl.handle.net/2027/spo.bbp2372.1992.072). I have successfully implemented my own delay/feedback loops using block diagrams programmed in C in the Arduino IDE (but am unable to analyse them mathematically).

Instead of using the more usual method of delay line length interpolation to get the required frequency resolution for a musical scale, I chose to simply change the sample rate (~40kHz to 100kHz). This makes good sounds using elementary loops containing delays, non linear elements and simple one zero FIR and one pole IIR filters.

Apart from being very simple to implement, the varying feedback loop sample rate gives smooth frequency transitions and harmonic development (through non linearities).

Textbook descriptions of filters (eg DC blocking, biQuad) assume a fixed sample rate sampling an existing signal. In my application the signal is being generated at the sample rate, which is variable. Every time I read about filters I get confused on that account. What are the implications in general terms of the attempt to use standard filter structures in the context of the above variable sample rate oscillator/waveguides?

Edit: In other words the frequency of the signal is a direct function of the sample rate (and delay line length).

Answer (score 1):

If your physics are more easily/accurately solved using a variable (per voice) samplerate, then that seems viable. Doing per-voice asynchronous samplerate conversion should be trivial compute and code wise but does add some small amount of delay.

If you want to design a constant sample-rate digital filter that "scales" behaviour with an input parameter (such as physical size/length), the straight-forward textbook topologies require you to recalculate coefficients, and there will typically be some "scaling error" particularly at high frequencies relative to the sampling rate. There may be other topologies that are better suited to running at a fixed rate but having "frequency scale" as a driving parameter.

A filter design that is statically locked to the sample rate (because the driving physical parameter happens to drive the sample rate) seems to be able to maintain a constant algorithm.

What happens to filter state if you modulate the sample rate "fast" relative to the significant frequency-domain behaviour I am not able to think about from the hip. My hunch is that it could introduce undesired behaviour?

Also, would not the "linear resonant system" (i.e. the horn) potentially have a driving parameter different from that of the mouth piece, meaning that simply executing the code faster and slower (then resampling it) might not be enough? If it was (in the extreme case), it should be sufficient to have a single sampled waveform and play that back at different sample rates (your basic ROMpler system).

Comment: If the driving parameter is a linear function of the breath pressure, I get a noisy oscillator. If the driving parameter is static I get a simple square wave oscillator.
If the driving parameter is filtered and non-linear I get a musical tone.